# Scrollview not scrolling smoothly from top to bottom

Tags: ios

i am loading 10-10 records with different view sizes in the scrollview after loading 120 records. scrolling is not smoothly working. while scrolling top to bottom and scrolling strucks for 1sec and then scrollinf

Comment: In Xcode: Product Menu -> Profile -> Time Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shared your code, it's hard to come to any conclusions, but one of the reasons might be that you have set `pagingEnabled` to `true`. So here's what you should do :

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = false
```